# Why the denoise function of opencv is not working

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, noise-reduction

I'm a complete beginner in opencv so please do excuse me if my question is foolish .Basically I was messing around with `opencv` functions to explore their jobs but one of the function i.e `Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(mat,mat);` is not working I don't understand why. As per the error it's showing that we can only use `CV1,CV2 and CV3` which is there in my case but still I'm getting the error.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52478719/8027365) but it couldn't solve my problem .

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue ?

Code:

```
Mat tmp = new Mat (bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, tmp);


            Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(tmp,tmp);


            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp,bitmap);
```

Error:

```
 CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp:78: error: (-5) Unsupported image format! Only CV_8UC1, CV_8UC2 and CV_8UC3 are supported in function void cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, float, int, int)
]
    at org.opencv.photo.Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.photo.Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(Photo.java:57)
    at opengl.community.myopencvexample.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:83)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It is working for me, check which type of Mat object is tmp during runtime.

Comment: @unlut thanks a lot for your suggestion but how to do that ? and even if I'll check that then how can i change that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why fastNlMeansDenoisingColored() of openCV is giving error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473325/why-fastnlmeansdenoisingcolored-of-opencv-is-giving-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your library and your problem would be solved means if you're using 2.x then update it to opencv 3.0

Comment: If two questions have identical answers, they are duplicates. Instead of duplicating the answer, please flag the question as duplicate. Thanks!