# Why fastNlMeansDenoisingColored() of openCV is giving error?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm a rookie in `openCV` concept so please do excuse me if my question is foolish.Actually I'm trying to apply the `Photo.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored()` method but I don't understand why it's giving such error.

Code:

```
Mat tmp = new Mat (bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, tmp);

            Photo.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(tmp,tmp, 10, 10, 7, 21);


            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp,bitmap);
```

Error:

```
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp:91: error: (-5) Type of input image should be CV_8UC3! in function void cv::fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, float, float, int, int)
]
    at org.opencv.photo.Photo.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.photo.Photo.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(Photo.java:118)
    at opengl.community.myopencvexample.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:83)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @NizaSiwale Sorry I forgot to add it please check it now

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski sorry I forgot to add that now please check the error

Comment: do have the iso images in your build?

Comment: @NizaSiwale no I don't have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue by updating the openCV lib from 2.x to 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Download the [native libs](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/tree/master/sdk/native/libs) and put them in your `main/jniLibs` directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer sir . By the way could you please tell me what's the necessity of that ?

Comment: The native libs provide the compiled c source, the OpenCV SDK has to call them using `JNI (Jave Native Interface)`. The sdk is only provides a bridge to the native code

Comment: Yes you're right but I'm not using c++ so is it still necessary to add native libs ?

Comment: Yes it's necessary OpenCV is in c++, the opencvSDK for android is just an jni library that calls the native sdk

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: the problem remains the same sir