# Opencv's Photo library method is giving error

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm a complete beginner in opencv so please do excuse me if my question is foolish .Actually I was trying the following `opencv` function to reduce noise of an image but the function i.e `Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(mat,mat)` is not working I don't understand why. As per the error it's showing that we can only use `CV1,CV2 and CV3` which is there in my case but still I'm getting the error.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477540/7955779) but it couldn't solve my problem .

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue ?

Code:

```
Mat tmp = new Mat (bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, tmp);


            Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(tmp,tmp);


            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp,bitmap);
```

Error:

```
 CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/photo/src/denoising.cpp:78: error: (-5) Unsupported image format! Only CV_8UC1, CV_8UC2 and CV_8UC3 are supported in function void cv::fastNlMeansDenoising(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, float, int, int)
]
    at org.opencv.photo.Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.photo.Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(Photo.java:57)
    at opengl.community.myopencvexample.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:83)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How are you reading the image? Have you verified the `bitmap` is correctly holding the image (i.e. not `Null` or similar)? Edit: seeing the link you posted and that this exact error has shown up before, I'm guessing my original suggestion is probably not your problem.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks for your suggestion sir but I've checked the bitmap several times and it's not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your library and your problem would be solved means if you're using 2.x then update it to opencv 3.0